# Unable to distribute a react-native iOS app on the App Store

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, xcode7

I have developed an iOS mobile app in react-native that I want to distribute on the App Store. I have enrolled in the developer program and I will get a certificate soon. My react-native iOS app is running fine on the simulator.

This is my first iOS application and I have no idea how to distribute a react-native app on the App Store.

Currently I'm using React version: 0.14.8 and react-native version 0.29.0
I tried to create an Offline bundle but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you will follow the exact same steps for preparing and releasing an iOS app as you would when developing natively in Objective-C or Swift, and there are many guides for that on the web.

As for React Native-specific workflows, here are a few things you'll want to cover.

- **Create an offline bundle:** Sounds like you've already tried to do this, but didn't specify why it didn't work. From inside the project folder, I always run the following, which the app package then picks up just fine:

  `react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios`
- **Pointing to bundle:** Starting in RN v0.29, you no longer have to do the uncommenting mentioned in the old guide, it should pick up its source automatically.
- **Bump the Build #:** Inevitably you will end up submitting multiple builds to Apple for testing and approval. Don't forget to increase the Build number in your app package's Settings under General > Identity > Build.

[image: Screenshot of where the Build textbox is]

Other than those things, most everything else is not specific to React or React Native.

Comment: how can i submit app for testing to apple?

Comment: Generally, follow the steps above, and make sure you have your developer account all set up on https://developer.apple.com and in Xcode. Next, make sure that your device profile is set to "Generic iOS Device" (see the pic in the answer), and then go to Product > Archive. Your app will be compiled, and a new window opens that allows you to submit a build to Apple for testing.

Comment: while creating build getting an error no provisioning profile found.

Comment: @Deepak you're into new question territory here, but you'll want to follow the guidelines here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html) guide:

### Disabling the developer menu

> Building an app for distribution in the App Store requires using the
> Release scheme in Xcode. Apps built for Release will automatically
> disable the in-app developer menu. This will prevent your users from
> inadvertently accessing the menu in production.

### Using the offline bundle

> Set up your app to load your JavaScript, images, and other static
> assets from its resource bundle rather than the development server.
> This way you can test the app independently of the development server,
> and will allow you to distribute the app to beta testers and submit
> the app to the App Store.
>
> - Open ios/YourApp/AppDelegate.m
> - Uncomment the line, jsCodeLocation =
>   [[NSBundle mainBundle] ...